# Manifold AVG aggregation in Webi 4.2

Tags: average, aggregation, business-objects, webi

I am trying to produce a report in SAP BusinessObjects Webi 4.2 that has complex aggregation, however not having much luck.

I have data as follows:

[image: Source Data]

I am trying to create a variable that returns the average count of skills for Colleagues in each Store and Region, for example:

[image: Required Output 1]

And...

[image: Required Output 2]

I've tried `=AVERAGE(([Skills]) in ([Colleague]))` however, this seems to return the SUM rather than the average.

Apologies if I'm missing something simple... it's been a long day... and any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embrace the sum:

```
=Sum([Skills]) / Count([Colleague];All)
```

**Updated for comment**
If [Skills] is a variable, then it gets a little more complicated.  This worked for me with a copy of your sample data:

```
=Sum([Skills] ForEach ([Store];[Colleague]) ) 
 / Count(1 In ([Region];[Store];[Colleague]);All)
```

Note that if you have other lower-level dimensions in the block, then you will need to add them to both the `ForEach` and `Count` functions.

I got a slightly different result that you for East Anglia (3.22), but based on my manual calculation, 3.22 is correct.

Comment: Thanks... this isn't quite doing what I am expecting though... I think it may be because [Skills] is actually a variable with =count([SkillGroups]).

I think the above is returning the total SkillGroups that all colleagues are members of, divided by the total of colleagues.